# How to increment time by 2 hours 30 min

Tags: excel, datetime, formatting, excel-formula, worksheet-function

Cell A1 has value `Sat 10/17/2015 3:46 PM`. I want to add 2 hours 30 minutes to it so the value in cell B1 should be: `Sat 10/17/2015 6:16 PM`.
I tried using this formula in B1:

```
=A1+TIME(2,30,0)
```

but it returns `#VALUE!`.

What do I need to do to achieve `Sat 10/17/2015 6:16 PM`?

Comment: Is the value `Sat 10/17/2015 3:46 PM` text or is that a formatted version of a date object?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try:

```
=DATEVALUE(MID(A1,4,18))+TIMEVALUE(RIGHT(A1,8))+5/48
```

formatted as:

```
ddd mm/dd/yyyy hh:mm AM/PM
```

Comment: Just want to ask , how to do it in VBA? and how you decided to add 5/48 in DATEVALUE(MID(A1,4,18))+TIMEVALUE(RIGHT(A1,8))+5/48 (Because if i have to add 3 hours instead of 2 hours 30 minutes then i have to change that value) Thanks

Comment: Got it.. Thanks ...But how you decided to add 5/48 in DATEVALUE(MID(A1,4,18))+TIMEVALUE(RIGHT(A1,8))+5/48 (Because if i have to add 3 hours instead of 2 hours 30 minutes then i have to change that value)

Comment: Instead of adding 5/48 could just add `TIME(2,30,0)`

Comment: But simpler and more to the point of adding hour, minutes and seconds. Don't just count the characters written, count the calculations to reach the 5/48, 2.5/24, 3./24, etc.; instead of doing all those calculations "just" let excel do it, that's called efficiency...